# my Regex for xml tags is not working

Tags: c++, regex

```
regex starttag("(.*)<\w*>");
regex endtag("(.*)<\/\w*>");
regex taganddata(".*<\w*>\w*<\/\w*>");
```

This is what I have but it doesn't work when trying to match and I don't know why.

```
this is a start tag: " <House>"
this is a end tag: " </House>"
This is a data tag: " <City>Allentown</City>"
```

Also the string to be matched is one line of the xml file (so it has white space at the beginning for indents) because I am going line by line.

I used regex and other services and it looked like it matches there but not in my c++ program using the regex stl

This is what is not working

```
if (regex_match(line, starttag))
{
    cout << "Start tag" << endl;
}
if (regex_match(line, endtag))
{
    cout << "End tag" << endl;
}
if (regex_match(line, taganddata))
{
    cout << "Data and Tags" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hint: `"\s*<\w*>"` is a string containing the letter s, an asterisk, a less-than sign, the letter w, an asterisk, and a greater than sign. It does not contain any backslashes. It should also generate a compiler warning.

Comment: but doesn't \w mean any word character?

Comment: But your string doesn't contain \w, it contains w.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex needs to be escaped properly. i.e. the forward slashes need to be properly escaped

```
regex starttag("(.*)<\\w*>");
regex endtag("(.*)<\\/\\w*>");
regex taganddata(".*<\\w*>\\w*<\\/\\w*>");
```

Alternatively, you can use the [**Raw string format:**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

```
regex starttag(R"((.*)<\w*>)");
regex endtag(R"((.*)<\/\w*>)");
regex taganddata(R"(.*<\w*>\w*<\/\w*>)");
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know what. Thanks